# plan moveL moveP

Tags: ros, rviz, moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi

i have multiple waypoints (`std::vector<geometry_msgs::Pose> waypoints`)

i can plan these waypoints using computeCartesianPath:

```
computeCartesianPath( waypoints, eef_step, jump_threshold, trajectory, true );
```

i think "computeCartesianPath" equals moveL function.

how can i plan moveP

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/394045/plan-movel-movep/) by [omeranar1](https://answers.ros.org/users/45833/omeranar1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2022-01-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-01-11**:
You'll want to explain (for others) what "moveP" actually does. I believe you're referring to a specific motion type on Universal Robots, but it's not universal terminology. So without describing what you're trying to achieve, it's going to be difficult to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`MoveP` will move the tool in linear motion at constant speed with circular blends. The size of the blend radius is per default a shared value for all the waypoint. A smaller value will make the path turn sharper whereas a higher value will make the path smoother. [reference](https://www.universal-robots.com/articles/ur/programming/circular-path-using-movepmovec/)

The [Pilz Industrial Motion Planner](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/pilz_industrial_motion_planner/pilz_industrial_motion_planner.html#using-the-planner) provides such an implementation in MoveIt. [reference prior question](https://answers.ros.org/question/380628/blend-radius-with-moveitrosur5e/)

> A specialized MoveIt capability takes
> a moveit_msgs::MotionSequenceRequest
> as input. The request contains a list
> of subsequent goals as described above
> and an additional blend_radius
> parameter. If the given blend_radius
> in meter is greater than zero, the
> corresponding trajectory is merged
> together with the following goal such
> that the robot does not stop at the
> current goal

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2022-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1